# i and j of my for loops are getting higher then they should in my minimax algorithm

Tags: javascript, for-loop, minimax

**My current code looks something like this:**

```
let bestScore = -Infinity
let move;
for(i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < board.length; j++)
    {
        if(whiteFrameNumber.includes(board[i][j])) // spot is available
        {
            const fieldBefore = board[i][j]
            board[i][j] = cross
            const score = minimax(board, 0, false)
            board[i][j] = fieldBefore
            if(score > bestScore)
            {
                bestScore = score
                move = {i, j}
            }
        }
    }
}
board[move.i][move.j] = cross
```

**and my minimax algorithm:**

```
function minimax(board, depth, isMaximizing)
{
    const result = checkWinner(board)
    if(result !== 'noone won')
    {
        let score
        if(result === cross) score = 1
        else if(result === circle) score = -1
        else if(result === 'tie') score = 0
    }

    if(isMaximizing)
    {
        const bestScore = -Infinity
        for(i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < board.length; j++)
            {
                if(whiteFrameNumber.includes(board[i][j]))  // spot is available
                {
                    const fieldBefore = board[i][j]
                    boardi[i][j] = cross
                    const score = minimax(board, depth + 1, false)
                    boardi[i][j] = fieldBefore
                    bestScore = Math.max(score, bestScore)
                }
            }
        }
        return bestScore
    }
    else
    {
        const bestScore = Infinity
        for(i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < board.length; j++)
            {
                if(whiteFrameNumber.includes(board[i][j])) // spot is available
                {
                    const fieldBefore = board[i][j]
                    boardi[i][j] = circle
                    const score = minimax(board, depth + 1, true)
                    boardi[i][j] = fieldBefore
                    bestScore = Math.min(score, bestScore)
                }
            }
        }
        return bestScore
    }
}
```

**I get the error: TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined**

**I also got: TypeError: Cannot set property '3' of undefined**

Through debugging I found out that 'j' in the main loop gets set to 3 after the minimax function.
I have no idea how and why but it would explain the error.

I didn't find any solution through further debugging so I have no idea how to proceed.

Sorry for my bad english ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the same `i` and `j` variables in the main loop and the `minimax()` function. So the loops in `minimax()` are updating the variables in the caller.

Make the variables local to each function by declaring them with `let` or `var`.

```
for (let i = ...) {
    for (let j = ...) {
        ...
    }
}
```